# Change email subjects for some specific email notifications in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications, subject

I would like to standardize structure of email subjects *(for all Woocommerce emails notifications).*
Im using all available filters [from here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-email-subject-lines/)

But what about “On hold”, “Cancelled”, “Refunded” and “Failed order” email subjects?
Is there way to change email subject for those emails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below the 4 hooked functions with the correct filter hooks, that will allow you to customize the email subjects for “On hold”, “Cancelled”, “Refunded” and “Failed order” notifications:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_customer_on_hold_order', 'customizing_on_hold_email_subject', 10, 2 );
function customizing_on_hold_email_subject( $formated_subject, $order ){
    return __("This is the custom on hold order email notification subject", "woocommerce");
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_cancelled_order', 'customizing_cancelled_email_subject', 10, 2 );
function customizing_cancelled_email_subject( $formated_subject, $order ){
    return __("This is the custom on cancelled email notification subject", "woocommerce");
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_customer_refunded_order', 'customizing_refunded_email_subject', 10, 2 );
function customizing_refunded_email_subject( $formated_subject, $order ){
    return __("This is the custom on refunded email notification subject", "woocommerce");
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_failed_order', 'customizing_failed_email_subject', 10, 2 );
function customizing_failed_email_subject( $formated_subject, $order ){
    return __("This is the custom on failed email notification subject", "woocommerce");
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

> You can use the `WC_Order` object argument `$order` to customize the subjects with dynamic order data…
>
> **Like for Example** *(with dynamic order ID and order formatted date modified)*:
>
> ```
> add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_cancelled_order', 'customizing_cancelled_email_subject', 10, 2 );
> function customizing_cancelled_email_subject( $formated_subject, $order ){
>     $modified = $order->get_date_modified(); // Get date modified WC_DateTime object
>     return sprintf( __('Order #%d  was cancelled on %s', 'woocommerce'), $order->get_id(), $modified->date_i18n( 'l jS \of F Y \a\t h:i:s A' ) );
> }
> ```

related: [Change email subject for custom order statuses in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51649117/change-email-subject-for-custom-order-statuses-in-woocommerce-3/51650199#51650199)